# How to block unregistered users?

Tags: support, profile-page, low-quality-posts, filtering, unregistered-users

I have not seen a single good question or answer by an unregistered user yet.

I can understand that some people are still interested in searching for the "gold nugget" in these very special contributions (see also [Can unregistered users be blocked from answering on some sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263867/can-unregistered-users-be-blocked-from-answering-on-some-sites)). But for me it is just a big waste of time and I want to filter them out.

How can I make contributions by unregistered users invisible for me?

Comment: You can't.  Who posts something doesn't matter.  The content does.

Comment: @fbueckert As explained and in agreement with the experience of many other users there is hardly ever a good contribution by an unregistered user on one of the big sx platforms. We are not talking about Area51 and the very small ones.

Comment: Where it is doesn't matter.  The ability to filter by user isn't a feature on the SE network; we focus on content, and content alone.  [See my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379645/1197934) for reasoning.

Comment: If you just want to place ads between any content this would be different, but the people, who want to use sx are not interested in just `any content`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write a userscript that retrieves `user_type` from [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=200558&filter=!3LyErCJG1Mh-A0_2D0&site=meta&run=true) and hides the post if the type is "unregistered".

Regarding questions, a [few large sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227114) block questions from unregistered users already. You can make a case that another site should do the same by raising the issue on that site's meta: for example, [Let's require registration to ask a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17244/lets-require-registration-to-ask-a-question) led to this being done on Mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

> I have not seen a single good question or answer by an unregistered user yet.

You know what you're supposed to do with those posts, right? Downvote them, and if appropriate, flag them as 'should be closed' / 'very low quality' / 'not an answer'. One of the great things about Stack Exchange is that bad content is usually quickly hidden or even deleted. That's because of all the moderating work done by the community, including you, and it's very hard to properly moderate posts you can't see. Just like real life, you can't just enjoy the good parts; you have a responsibility as a Stack Exchange citizen.